# save matlab function to disk using scipy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Using Python, I want to write a Matlab struct to disk. This is fairly simple using scipy.io module: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/tutorial/io.html

However, I want one of the fields of the struct to be a function of the form `@sqrt` so that when I load the .mat file to disk in matlab, I get this functionality:

```
>> myStruct = load('MyStruct.mat')
>> myStruct.myFunction(5)
ans =
    2.2361
```

But I can't find how to do this. Simply putting in the string of '@sqrt' into one of the struct fields doesn't work.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with SciPy, but I can think of a possible workaround. Store the function name string instead of its handle, and in MATLAB use [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
myfunc = str2func(myStruct.myFunction);
myfunc(5)
```

If you really need a one-liner, you can use [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html) instead:

```
feval(myStruct.myFunction, 5)
```